# Change password for a group based on columns of that group

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in database where I have different fields like name, email, mobile number, group etc, and a password field, plus other fields which are unrelated to the question.
Now, I want to change the password based on whether the mail is provided or the group is provided.
The basic `sql` query for changing my password is:

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE test_taker SET test_taker_password = CONCAT(test_taker_password, SUBSTRING($select1, '$from1', '$to1')) where test_taker_email = '$mail' OR test_taker_group = '$group'");
```

and I am using this inside as:

```
$setRec = mysqli_query($con,"select * from test_taker where test_taker_email = '$mail' OR test_taker_group = '$group' ");

while($rec = mysqli_fetch_array($setRec))
{   
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE test_taker SET test_taker_password = CONCAT(test_taker_password, SUBSTRING($select1, '$from1', '$to1')) where test_taker_email = '$mail' OR test_taker_group = '$group'");
    $password=$rec['test_taker_password'];
}
```

and when I tried with mail, it works perfectly fine, but when I try with group, the while loop replicates for the number of times the number of rows obtained in the setRec.
 For example, if the password was supposed to be abcd10, ab from name, cd from email, 10 from mobile, and there are two rows in the given group, then password returned is ababcdcd1010.
Please tell me how to solve this group problem, without harming the mail one.

Comment: try with `WHERE (test_taker_email = '$mail' OR test_taker_group = '$group')`

Comment: save your password as a hash on systems that matter. Coupon databases for home use don't qualify necessarily

Comment: why use a loop? The update query will target the same records that the select query will retrieve so the update query is the only one that you should use by the looks of things. Also, the update has some variables that are not defined in the code shown -where are they defined?

Answer (score 0):

As you have first use select query, with the `OR` condition, it will result you number of rows. and you have apply while loop on that record. Now the thing happened is, Whenever you are applying the while loop it will execute multiple times as your record counters come ups. and in while loop you are executing records using `OR` condition which every time updates your records.

```
$setRec = mysqli_query($con,"select * from test_taker where test_taker_email = '$mail' OR test_taker_group = '$group' ");
```

Suppose this query returns 10 records with the combination of 
`where test_taker_email = '$mail' OR test_taker_group = '$group'`

and also update query will perform action on all the 10 records as you give where clause `where test_taker_email = '$mail' OR test_taker_group = '$group'`

so each and every time when your loop executes it will perform action on all of the records which the condition full fills.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed the point of the loop then you should be able to do the update with a single update statement - but by embedding variables directly within the sql you have made it vulnerable to sql injection. The code below uses a prepared statement ( procedural style to follow your original code ) and should update the relevant records safely.

```
$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'xxx'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'xxx';
$con    =   mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );    

$sql = 'update `test_taker` set 
        `test_taker_password` = concat( `test_taker_password`, substring( ?, ?, ? ) ) 
        where `test_taker_email` = ? or `test_taker_group` = ?';

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init( $con );
$res  = mysqli_stmt_prepare( $stmt, $sql );

if( $res ){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "siiss", $select1, $from1, $to1, $mail, $group );
    mysqli_stmt_execute( $stmt );
    mysqli_stmt_close( $stmt );
} else {
    echo "Error!";
}

mysqli_close( $con );
```

Answer (score 0):

i finally solved it like this:

```
 $connectorvar = mysqli_query($con,"select * from templatetable WHERE templateid = '$test123' ORDER BY orderuser");
while($rec = mysqli_fetch_array($test1)){
    while($connectorwhile = mysqli_fetch_array( $connectorvar) ){
        $select1 = $connectorwhile['selectfromuser'];
        $from1 = $connectorwhile['fromuser'];
        $to1 = $connectorwhile['touser'];

$setRec = mysqli_query($con,"select * from test_taker where (test_taker_email = '$mail' OR test_taker_group = '$group') ");
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE test_taker SET test_taker_password = CONCAT(test_taker_password, SUBSTRING($select1, '$from1', '$to1')) where test_taker_email = '$mail' OR test_taker_group = '$group'");
}}
```

where i added the orderuser part so that the query can run only the number of times the user intends it to.... thank you guys for helping me out...